# R igraph layouts are not performing as they should

Tags: r, layout, igraph

I'm running some small graphs using igraph in r, and I'm not able to replicate some pretty standard layout functions.  My edges are different lengths and overlapping and just messy.  I've been working and searching for about 1.5 with no progress.  This example below is giving me this graph.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(123)
x <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, 
         replace=TRUE)
y <- sample( LETTERS, 100, 
         replace=TRUE)
mydata <- data.frame(x,y)

my.plot <- graph_from_data_frame(mydata,directed = F)
l <- layout_with_fr(my.plot)
plot(my.plot, layout=l)
```

[image]

I have about 5 individual networks about the same size as the example.  Is there layout functions that will 'facet' the different graphs similar to ggplot2?

[image]

Comment: does `par(mfrow=c(2,3), mar=c(0,0,0,0))` work for you?

Comment: @G5W9, I didn't know this existed.  It seems like it can be used to facet the graphs pretty well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that this is not unanswered ...

You can get the effect that you want by setting `par(mfrow=c(2,3))`.  Because igraph tends to leave big margins,  I would recommend also setting the margins. So,    run everything up to and including your `layout`statement.  Then

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3), mar=c(0,0,0,0)) 
for(i in 1:5) { plot(my.plot, layout=l) }
```

[image: Multiple graphs]

Of course, I am just plotting the same thing 5 times.  You will want to make each of your different plots.